# How to select latest record with same unique foreign id?

Tags: php, mysql, phpfox

Hi i want to select the record with latest updated **status** using **task_id** as foreign key, 
I want this in Phpfox based query, but if can solve let me know the general query for this scnario

```
id     task_id   status
--------------------------
 1       2           1
 2       3           3
 3       2           3
 4       2           2  <------- select this record
 5       4           1
```

Comment: You want the row with the highest id for a given task id?

Comment: last updated status with task_id = 2

Comment: It's not clear what you want. What's unique about that row?

Comment: What do you mean by "last updated"? Is there a timestamp somewhere?

Comment: there is no time_stamp column in row i want record with task_id = 2, it's clear see the example table in question

Comment: You need to save the last updated time

Comment: if i add a column time_stamp then what will be scenario to fetch data in same situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? `task_id = 2` with last updated status(or I can say last inserted in table):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE task_id = 2 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```